# ContentBlockByName() not inheriting parent styling when added to existing HTML content block in Templated Email

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder

"Sample" HTML content block code:

```
This is un-styled HTML code
```

Code when added to an HTML content

```
     ...<tr>
       <td align="center" style="font-size:11px;">
        %%=ContentBlockByName("Sample")-%%<td>..
```

When performing a send preview and test send, the copy within "Sample" is left-aligned and the font-size is larger than 11px. It appears to be using the browser defaults. If I copy the un-styled HTML directly in, the styling inherits as expected.

Why is this occurring and is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML Blocks returned by ContentBlockByKey are wrapped in table html that leads to your realignment. If you don't want it to be wrapped you can either:

- Create your block as Code Snippet instead of HTML block
- Wrap your output with ReplaceList ampscript function like below

`%%=ReplaceList(ContentBlockByKey('Sample'), '', '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" role="presentation" style="min-width: 100%; " class="stylingblock-content-wrapper"><tr><td class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner">', '</td></tr></table>')=%%`

Comment: Thank you for the background and for the options. Code Snippet worked great and is the preferred option.